# Keyboard shortcut for Inserting signature in Outlook 2007 or latter?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a default keyboard shortcut to insert my signature in a reply email in Outlook 2007 or latter? If not how to create shortcut for adding signature while replying every mail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there a default keyboard shortcut to insert my signature in a reply email?

**Outlook 2007**:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, then <kbd>g</kbd>, select signature from the list and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>,then <kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd> will open the signature dialog box to add or edit the signature.

**Outlook 2010**:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd>:
>
> - Add Signature to message: I<kbd>n</kbd>sert => <kbd>A</kbd>dd <kbd>S</kbd>ignature

Source [Outlook 2010 Shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Outlook_2010.html)

Comment: I think I wrote the same answer. But this is not working for Him.

Comment: No you didn't. You missed out the <a>

Comment: For Ms-outlook 2007 it's not working. I didn't try it on MS-outlook 2010. but with the reference of your answer I finally get my answer. Alt+N, then g and then I select my signature form the list and press enter. Alt+N,then G,S will open the signature dialog box where we can add or edit the signature. You can modify the ans so that I can accept it.

Comment: @MANISH Thanks for the comment. Answer updated for 2007

Comment: Alt - n & g worked on my win7.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, for Outlook for Office 365, I could not make the other solutions work for me.  Instead, I found the best solution was to navigate to `ribbon > signatures > signatures`.  From there, on the right hand side you can set the default signature for both new emails and for replies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a YouTube video that shows it! At least allows hotkeys for text (signatures, quotes, etc.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pC12VRyxcgo

Steps:

1. highlight text
2. file -> options
3. Mail
4. Spelling and Autocorrect
5. AutoCorrect options
6. Your text is in the "with" section. Type something new in the "replace" section, click "Add" below, and then OK.